# How to create a conditional in select query | mySQL

Tags: mysql

Essentially I have a table that contains a name of a person and two date columns one called `ready_date` and `get_date`

Sometimes a `person` may not have a `ready_date` but will always have `get_date`. Other times a record can contain both a `ready_date` and `get_date`

Based on the logic below I would like the select query to create a query column called date that displays either a `ready_date` or `get_date`.

**LOGIC:**

If a `person` has `ready_date` and `get_date` let `date` equal `ready_date`

If a `person` has `get_date` but no `ready_date` let `date` equal `get_date`

Example of how query results should look like. Is this something that is possible to accomplish?

[image]

Comment: Seems like `IF (ready_date <> '', ready_date, get_date) AS 'Date'`.

Answer (score 1):

What you could use is [`if()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html)

```
SELECT Person,  IF (ready_date IS NOT NULL, ready_date, get_date) AS 'Date'
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just use `coalesce()`:

```
select 
    t.*, 
    coalesce(ready_date, get_date) date
from mytable t
```

`coalesce()` returns its first non-null argument.

- *if a person has `get_date` but no `ready_date`*, then the expression returns `get_date` (since the first argument, `ready_date`, is `null`)
- *if a person has `get_date` and `ready_date`*, then the expression returns `ready_date` (because it's the first argument and it is not `null`)

Answer (score 1):

MySQL provides a number of ways to do this kind of operation:

```
SELECT Person, IF(ready_date IS NULL, get_date, ready_date) ...
SELECT Person, IFNULL(ready_date, get_date) ...
SELECT Person, CASE WHEN ready_date IS NOT NULL THEN ready_date ELSE get_date END ...
SELECT Person, COALESCE(ready_date, get_date) ...
```

The first two are basically equivalent; but the 4th (COALESCE) accepts more than two arguments, and returns the first non-null one from the list. (It's the equivalent of `CASE WHEN a IS NOT NULL THEN a WHEN b IS NOT NULL THEN b ... ELSE NULL END`

Bonus facts:
In older versions of MS Sql Server, IF() is not supported so CASE must be used (and can be seen as more portable). MS Sql Server's equivalent to `IFNULL()` is `ISNULL()`.... which is a completely different function in MySql.